# Flex left div fill remaining space when right div is at maximum width

Tags: css, flexbox

I have two divs inside a flex box. Div A is on the left, and div B is on the right.

I would like div A to take up 60% of the flex box, and div B to take up 40% of the flex box. As you can imagine, my css will look like this:

```
.container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: start; 
    flex-direction: column;
}
.div_a {
    width: 60%;
}
.div_b {
    width: 40%;
}
```

Also, the browser will look like this:

[image]

Now, I would like div B to have a maximum and minimum width, the code will now look like this:

```
.container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: start; 
    flex-direction: column;
}
.div_a {
    width: 60%;
}
.div_b {
    width: 40%;
    max-width: 768px; 
    min-width: 480px; 
}
```

Unfortunately, this will lead to this situation large browsers.

[image]

When Div B has reached its maximum width, I would like div A to fill up the rest of the space, like this:

[image]

Any ideas or fixes would be appreciated, thank you very much in advance.

I should mention that `min-width: 60%` for Div A produces the same situation, unfortunately.

Comment: flex-grow:1 to A ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a perfect case where you would turn towards the property `flex-grow`.
Since you're working with a 60%/40% size, you can use `flex-grow:6` and `flex-grow:4`, or alternatively: `flex-grow:3` and `flex-grow:2`.  Or even: `flex-grow:1.5` and `flex-grow:1` since the property also accepts decimals!

```
.div_a {
    flex-grow:3;
}
.div_b {
    flex-grow: 2;
    max-width: 768px; 
    min-width: 480px; 
}
```

`flex-grow` is a property that will tell the parent (flexbox) to divide the available width into whatever the sum is of the amount of `flex-grow` specified in its child elements. By limiting the max width of `.div_b`, you tell flexbox to stop increasing the width after it reached that max, and the remaining width will be reserved for the other elements (`.div_a` in this case).

### Also

I do want to point out that you're using `flex-direction:column`, but you're trying to create a row based layout. It's a better idea to use `flex-flow: row nowrap`. Which is a shorthand to declare both `flex-direction` and `flex-wrap` together and, with the value `row nowrap` will tell the parent to force everything on one line in a horizontal layout.

```
.container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: start; 
    // flex-direction: column;
    flex-flow: row nowrap;
}
```